# R: How to get the maximum value of a datetime column in a time series data

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, max, time-series

I am working on a time series data. I have 2 date time columns and 1 fiscal week column. I have given an example where I have a situation like below and I need to get the MAX of the EditDate.

```
EditDate <- c("2015-04-01 11:40:13", "2015-04-03 02:54:45","2015-04-07 11:40:13")
ID <- c("DL1X8", "DL1X8","DL1X8")
Avg <- c(38.1517, 38.1517, 38.1517)
Sig <- c(11.45880000, 11.45880000, 11.45880000)
InsertDate <- c("2015-04-03 9:40:00", "2015-04-03 9:40:00",2015-04-10 9:40:00)
FW <- c("39","39","40")

df1 <- data.frame(EditDate , ID, Avg, Sig, InsertDate, FW)
```

This returns

```html
+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------+--------------------+----+
|   EditDate          | ID    | Avg     |   Sig       |    InsertDate      | FW |
+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------+--------------------+----+
| 2015-04-01 11:40:13 | DL1X8 | 38.1517 | 11.45880000 | 2015-04-03 9:40:00 | 39 |
| 2015-04-03 02:54:45 | DL1X8 | 38.1517 | 11.45880000 | 2015-04-03 9:40:00 | 39 |
| 2015-04-07 11:40:13 | DL1X8 | 38.1517 | 11.45880000 | 2015-04-10 9:40:00 | 40 |
+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------+--------------------+----+
```

The desired output that I want is

```html
+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------+--------------------+----+
|   EditDate          | ID    | Avg     |   Sig       |    InsertDate      | FW |
+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------+--------------------+----+
| 2015-04-07 11:40:13 | DL1X8 | 38.1517 | 11.45880000 | 2015-04-10 9:40:00 | 40 |
+---------------------+-------+---------+-------------+--------------------+----+
```

I tried using sqldf  using the library(RH2) but it takes a lot of time to run.

```
df2 <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df1 
                        WHERE (EditDate = (SELECT MAX(EditDate) FROM df1))
                        ORDER BY EditDate ASC")
```

I am not sure if it could be done using the dplyr package. Could someone provide inputs on how I could optimize this using dplyr or any other alternatives?

Comment: It shouldn't take a long time to run.  Note that the first time you use RH2 in a session it will load java and that takes a long time.  Also, note that you could also try it with SQLite in which case an extension to SQL is available so it could be written as `sqldf("select max(EditDate) EditDate, ID, Avg, Sig, InsertDate, FW from df1")` .  Adding an index to EditDate might help although the query is so simple it might not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one liner with base R

```
df1[which.max(as.POSIXct(df1$InsertDate)), ]
#              EditDate    ID     Avg     Sig         InsertDate FW
# 3 2015-04-07 11:40:13 DL1X8 38.1517 11.4588 2015-04-10 9:40:00 40
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[which.max(as.POSIXct(InsertDate))]
#               EditDate    ID     Avg     Sig         InsertDate FW
# 1: 2015-04-07 11:40:13 DL1X8 38.1517 11.4588 2015-04-10 9:40:00 40
```

Answer (score 4):

Just with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)

df1[ymd_hms(EditDate)==max(ymd_hms(EditDate)), ]
```

or `df1[EditDate==as.character(max(ymd_hms(EditDate))), ]`

Answer (score 1):

use libraries `data.table` and `lubridate` as following:

```
 library(data.table)
 library(lubridate)
 setDT(df1)
 df1[,EditDate := ymd_hms(EditDate)]
 res <- df1[EditDate = max(EditDate)]
```