# Picking out column name for maximum dates

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, lapply, posixct

I have a data set that is a follow up of individuals over a course of number of years. Thus I have list of dates where events have occurred. I have copied a sample of data ( there is only 2 dates here but in my actual data there are more columns). I want to select the maximum date and the column which this date came from. I have done this using other software but need to do it in R and I am not sure how to proceed.

I have managed to get maximum date of an individual however I have not managed to get the column which this data came from.

I used this to get maximum date

```
apply(testdata[], 1, max, na.rm=T)
```

I have tried to do following and variations of that which does not work

```
colnames(testdata)[apply(testdata[], 1, which.max)]
```

But above did not return anything. I know this is due to the fact that dates are S3 class and which.max doesnt seem to work with that class.

I found [R: How to get the maximum value of a datetime column in a time series data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686522/r-how-to-get-the-maximum-value-of-a-datetime-column-in-a-time-series-data) the isue is that this is for single data, I tried to use

```
colnames(testdata)[apply(as.POSIXct(testdata[]),1,which.max]
```

but this would produce an error.

Therefore, I am not sure how to get the column names. Any ideas?

End result should look like this:

```
date1            date2  ID  Maximumdate columnName
09/09/2016  09/09/2016  27  09/09/2016  date2
13/09/2016              28  13/09/2016  date1
14/09/2016  15/09/2016  29  15/09/2016  date2
16/09/2016  16/09/2016  30  16/09/2016  date2
29/09/2016  20/09/2016  31  29/09/2016  date1
06/10/2016  30/09/2016  32  06/10/2016  date1
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data please?

Comment: @Gainz my data is like the end result with date1 - date 100 in a data frame (except last two columns obviously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the 'Maximumdate' with `pmax` , and the 'columnName' by looping over the rows with  `pmap`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with('date')), dmy) %>% 
   mutate(Maximumdate = pmax(date1, date2, na.rm = TRUE), 
   columnName = pmap(.[1:2], ~ names(which.max(rev(c(...))))))
#      date1      date2 Maximumdate columnName
#1 2016-09-09 2016-09-09  2016-09-09      date2
#2 2016-09-13       <NA>  2016-09-13      date1
#3 2016-09-14 2016-09-15  2016-09-15      date2
#4 2016-09-16 2016-09-16  2016-09-16      date2
#5 2016-09-29 2016-09-20  2016-09-29      date1
#6 2016-10-06 2016-09-30  2016-10-06      date1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(date1 = c("09/09/2016", "13/09/2016", "14/09/2016", 
"16/09/2016", "29/09/2016", "06/10/2016"), date2 = c("09/09/2016", 
NA, "15/09/2016", "16/09/2016", "20/09/2016", "30/09/2016")),
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Running this gives me error: object dmy not found. Do I need to run another library?

Comment: @khoshnaw  Sorry, it is from `lubridate`

Comment: thank you for that, now i get an error that `columnName1` must be length 30 (the number of rows) or one not 0. Not sure what the issue is?

Comment: @khoshnaw  Is it based on the same data example.  I am not getting that errore

Comment: that is really strange, i have tested it on the example I supplied above, however I am now getting different error: Error: Result 1 must be a single string, not NULL of length 0. in addtion, i get warning messages - all formats failed to parse. No formats found. 

I have no other data in my work space, not sure why it causes such an error.

Comment: am I missing a particular library by any chance?

Comment: @khoshnaw  Let me copy the data I used with `dput`

Comment: @khoshnaw  Can you check the ouput and the data in my post

Comment: it works with your data set. Is it possibly use to the fact that my data is of format POSIXct and yours chr? Otherwise the data looks the same!

Comment: just figured it out, my dates are of format ymd and it was causing the errors! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the date columns to a numeric matrix, you can use `max.col` to return the index of the column which achieves the max value. In converting to numeric, I marked NAs as negative infinity so they won't be selected as the max, to match your row 2 result.

```
j <- max.col(sapply(df[1:2], function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), -Inf, as.numeric(x))))
df$Maximumdate <- df[cbind(seq(nrow(df)), j)]
df$columnName <- names(df)[j]

df
#        date1      date2 ID Maximumdate columnName
# 1 2016-09-09 2016-09-09 27  2016-09-09      date2
# 2 2016-09-13       <NA> 28  2016-09-13      date1
# 3 2016-09-14 2016-09-15 29  2016-09-15      date2
# 4 2016-09-16 2016-09-16 30  2016-09-16      date1
# 5 2016-09-29 2016-09-20 31  2016-09-29      date1
# 6 2016-10-06 2016-09-30 32  2016-10-06      date1
```

Data used is below. If the date columns are not actually dates but strings, you need to run the second part of the code below to convert them to dates.

```
df <- data.table::fread('
date1            date2  ID  Maximumdate columnName
09/09/2016  09/09/2016  27  09/09/2016  date2
13/09/2016  NA          28  13/09/2016  date1
14/09/2016  15/09/2016  29  15/09/2016  date2
16/09/2016  16/09/2016  30  16/09/2016  date2
29/09/2016  20/09/2016  31  29/09/2016  date1
06/10/2016  30/09/2016  32  06/10/2016  date1
', data.table = F)

df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], as.Date, format = '%d/%m/%Y')
```